# Oracle is having issues with hibernate generated query, generates query with _ in row num

Tags: oracle, hibernate-criteria

I am using hibernate and using criteria query, database is Oracle. The below is the query that gets generated.

"

```
WITH query AS (
      SELECT inner_query.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__ 
      FROM ( 
           select this_.MODIFIEDTIME as MODIFIED1_1_1_, 
                  this_.FIELDNAME as FIELDNAM2_1_1_, 
                  this_.EMPNBR as EMPNBR3_1_1_
           from EMPLOYEEAUDIT this_ 
           left outer join EMPLOYEE employee2_ on this_.EMPNBR=employee2_.EMPNBR 
       ) inner_query 
) 
SELECT MODIFIED1_1_1_,FIELDNAM2_1_1_,EMPNBR3_1_1_
FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ >= 1 
 AND __hibernate_row_nr__ < 10;"
```

It is throwing the below error:-
SQL Error: 911, SQLState: 22019
ORA-00911: invalid character

However, if i take the SQL query and repalce the **hibernate_row_nr** with hibernate_row_nr__ and run it in DbVisualizer it works. It seems Oracle is not able to recognize starting '_' as valid characters. How to fix this issue?

Below is my java code:-

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList(int start, int limit, AgSort sorter) throws UIFilterException {

    DetachedCriteria detached = getEmployeeListCriteria(sorter, filters);

    return (List<DealSetupAudit>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(detached, start, limit);
}

    private DetachedCriteria getEmployeeListCriteria(AgSort sorter) throws UIFilterException {
    DetachedCriteria detached = getBaseCriteria(DealSetupAudit.class, sorter);


    return detached;
}

protected <T> DetachedCriteria getBaseCriteria(Class<T> genericType, AgSort sorter) throws UIFilterException {

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(genericType);

    addSorter(criteria, sorter);
    return criteria;
}
    protected void addSorter(DetachedCriteria criteria, AgSort sort) {

    if (sort != null) {
        Order order = null;
        if (sort.getDir().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.DESC)) {
            order = Order.desc(sort.getColumn());
        } else {
            order = Order.asc(sort.getColumn());
        }
        criteria.addOrder(order);
    }
}
```

I am using Hibernate4, below is my application.properties :-

```
oracle.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
oracle.datasource.url=******
oracle.datasource.username=*****
oracle.datasource.password=*****
oracle.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

oracle.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: Please show java code to the question. Please also show hibernate XML configuration file.

Comment: I have added my java code and the properties file

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes? Usually a *really, really* bad idea. I'd suggest you to avoid such things and use valid column names / aliases.

```
SQL> select dname _invalid_alias_
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno = 10;
select dname _invalid_alias_
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character


SQL> select dname "_valid_alias_"
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno = 10;

_valid_alias_
--------------
ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, i am using detached criteria , hence the query is being formed by hibernate. i am not using native query. Or else i would have avoided _ in the 1st place for the row num , an suggestions?

Comment: No, sorry; I don't know hibernate. Hopefully, someone else will assist.